# How can i specify the resource to get from R.res.drawable dynamically?

Tags: android, resources

I have some videos stored dynamically on `R.res.raw`.

For example, I can acces to the video called v.mp4 with this line of code:

```
String fileName = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.v;
```

OK, but I will describe the video that i must open with a string ("v"). Then, I tried to do this, but it didn't works:

```
String fileName = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw+".v";
```

I can't do that, I get an error on R.raw

I also tried with this, but it doesn't works:

```
String fileName = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/res/raw/"+"v.mp4";
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get any resource Path then there are two ways :

1. Using Resource Name

   Syntax : `android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]`

   Example : If icon.png image file is available in res/drawable folder you can get path like :

   `String PATH="android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/icon";`
2. Using Resource Id

   Syntax : `android.resource://[package]/[resource_id]`

   Example : If icon.png image file is available in res/drawable folder you can get path:

   `String PATH="android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.drawable.icon;`

This were the examples to get the URI of any image file stored in drawable folder.

Similarly you can get URIs of res/raw folder also.

Comment: I am passing image path to html <img> tag that is not working for me.

Comment: I am passing path to html <img> tag to show in webview. It is not working for me , its not displaying image there.

Answer (score 2):

It must give you an error,
R.raw.v.mp4 (it must be as R.raw.v)  is gives an genarated int reference but not a String, so you cant get it by giving String path.You can print it and see it generates an int value that only application can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this as follows:

```
 android.resource://your package/raw/v
```